# How do I make TFS Workspace public in VS2010 TFS-api?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am working on an application that creates TFS workspaces in C# using the TFS Api. However, I want to be able to make the workspace public, but cannot find a way to do this. I have tried to look at this, but it doesn't seem the right way to go about it:

```
Workspace.Update Method(String, String, String, String, WorkingFolder[],
                        WorkspacePermissionProfile, Boolean)
```

Hope somebody can help.

BR,
Mette

Answer (score 2):

Use the builtin permissionprofile when creating a workspace:

```
var permissionProfile = WorkspacePermissionProfile.BuiltInProfiles[(int)WorkspacePermissionProfile.BuiltInIndexes.PublicLimited];
```

There are three types available: Private, Public and PublicLimited.

Comment: This no longer works against Azure Devops (cloud I've tried, not server). The Workspaces end up being Private anyway, regardless of if you set Public or PrivateLimited. This can break your world if you migrate from AzDo Server to Cloud.

(F.A.O Stack Overflow - I had to complete 12 captchas then got banned from logging in after messing them up on purpose in protest and finally sign in with GitHub - after signing into a google account - to write this. Nice work, well done.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2010/02/04/improvements-to-workspaces-in-tfs-2010.aspx) link, it might be useful to achieve what you are after.
The actual core of what you are after seems to be written in the section `Modifying the access control list`

Comment: I have looked at that, and perhaps it can to somewhat extent solve my problem. However, I am looking for a way to directly set the workspace to public for everyone, like one can do in the VS2010 GUI.